# iOS 11: Where did the right-side domain button go for Universal Links?

Tags: ios, ios11, ios-universal-links

Previously, in iOS 10, if you tapped a link that an installed app could handle (Universal Link), the app would open instead of Safari, but you'd see a button on the upper/right side of the app that would send you into Safari for the given URL. If you did this, then future links would open directly in Safari by default.

[image: iOS 10 Example]

Now in iOS 11 I cannot seem to get this right-side button to appear, and I've been searching google for an hour now and can't seem to find anyone talking about it? Am I doing something wrong in my app?

[image: iOS 11 Example]

Assuming this was deliberately removed in iOS 11, my theory is that it was because they couldn't figure out how to cram it into the right side area on iPhone X, as for some reason the indicators on the right side of the X "ear" are lower than they are on the left side, so there's less room for a forward button:

[image: iPhone X Example]

Please tell me I'm crazy and this option still exists in iOS 11 and I'm just doing something wrong?!

Comment: I do not see this option on iOS 11 as well. Possible reason why it got removed: many people would accidentally tap on this button and disable Universal Links for this App. Later this people would observe that Universal Links unexpectedly does not work (for this App).

Comment: What Oleksiy is saying makes sense. The only way to confirm is to get in touch with a UIKit Engineer. cc @smileyborg

Comment: Might be help! https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Anyone know how to reset iOS universal links for iOS 11? Don't think it is possible because of this...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're doing something wrong. Probably a bug or a feature Apple removed because they think the app always would be capable of handling the request right.